# constructing HTML with recursive loop in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, partial

Hello guys I have array of hashes:

```
@buttons = [{:serno=>1, :parent_serno=>0, :name=>"Home"},
{:serno=>2, :parent_serno=>0, :name=>"Search"},
{:serno=>3, :parent_serno=>0, :name=>"Search Payment"},
{:serno=>4, :parent_serno=>1, :name=>"Problematic Search Payment"},
{:serno=>5, :parent_serno=>1, :name=>"Cash Error"},
{:serno=>6, :parent_serno=>2, :name=>"Payment Note"},
{:serno=>7, :parent_serno=>2, :name=>"Search Payment By Category"},
{:serno=>8, :parent_serno=>3, :name=>"Search Payment New"},
{:serno=>9, :parent_serno=>3, :name=>"User Mangement"}]
```

I want to create div for each array hash (for example hash x) that's "parent_serno == 0", write their name inside the div and create another div inside of it, for every array hash that's "parent_serno == hash x [:serno]".

I tried to create partial:

```
<% for m in @buttons %>
    <% unless @parent.present? %>
        <% if m[:parent_serno] == 0 %>
            <div>
                <%= m[:name] %>
                <% @parent = m[:serno] %>
                <% if @buttons.find{ |b| b[:parent_serno] == @parent }.present? %>
                    <% @buttons.find{ |b| b[:parent_serno] == @parent }.each do %>
                        <%= render partial: "navbar", object: @parent %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end%>
    <% else %>
        <% if m[:parent_serno] == @parent %>
            <div>
                <%= m[:name] %>
                <% @parent = m[:serno] %>
                <% if @buttons.find{ |b| b[:parent_serno] == @parent }.present? %>
                    <% @buttons.find{ |b| b[:parent_serno] == @parent }.each do %>
                        <%= render partial: "navbar", object: @parent %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and render it in a another html.erb document, but apparently it just doesn't work :(
It only gives me the name of the first hash in the array and recursion stops there I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the partial you need should look something like this:

_button.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= button[:name] %>
  <% render partial: 'button', 
      collection: @buttons.select { |b| b[:parent_serno] == button[:serno] } %>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
...
<% render partial: 'button', 
    collection: @buttons.select { |b| b[:parent_serno] == 0 } %>
...
```